# Wordpress problem with header('Content-type: image/png');

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha

i'am trying to put a CAPTCHA in a wordpress custom plugin.

I did follow that tutorial :

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-own-captcha-and-contact-form-in-php--net-5362

```
<?php
session_start();
 
$permitted_chars = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  
function generate_string($input, $strength = 10) {
    $input_length = strlen($input);
    $random_string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
        $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
        $random_string .= $random_character;
    }
  
    return $random_string;
}
 
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);
 
imageantialias($image, true);
 
$colors = [];
 
$red = rand(125, 175);
$green = rand(125, 175);
$blue = rand(125, 175);
 
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  $colors[] = imagecolorallocate($image, $red - 20*$i, $green - 20*$i, $blue - 20*$i);
}
 
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $colors[0]);
 
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  imagesetthickness($image, rand(2, 10));
  $line_color = $colors[rand(1, 4)];
  imagerectangle($image, rand(-10, 190), rand(-10, 10), rand(-10, 190), rand(40, 60), $line_color);
}
 
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolors = [$black, $white];
 
$fonts = [dirname(__FILE__).'/Acme.ttf'];
 
$string_length = 6;
$captcha_string = generate_string($permitted_chars, $string_length);
 
$_SESSION['captcha_text'] = $captcha_string;
 
for($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++) {
  $letter_space = 170/$string_length;
  $initial = 15;
   
  imagettftext($image, 24, rand(-15, 15), $initial + $i*$letter_space, rand(25, 45), $textcolors[rand(0, 1)], $fonts[array_rand($fonts)], $captcha_string[$i]);
}
 
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

At first wordpress didn't find the font, but i manage to pass the error.
Then i call by shortcode the html. And i all i got is the alt and broken img. If i put directly the script in the function chrome tell me that my image contain errors. I did try to add utf8 encode and to pass the image without the header, none of that work.

```
    public function CAPTCHA_shortcode_function() {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div class="elem-group">
            <label for="captcha">Please Enter the Captcha Text</label>
            <img src="CAPTCHA-generate-image.php" alt="CAPTCHA" class="captcha-image"><i class="fas fa-redo refresh-captcha"></i>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha_challenge" pattern="[A-Z]{6}">
        </div>
        <?php

        $CAPTCHA = ob_get_clean();

        return $CAPTCHA;

    }
```

If you have any idea, something must be wrong ^^ Thanks a lot !

Comment: What do you get when you visit CAPTCHA-generate-image.php directly, via your browser address bar?

Comment: In local if i put the first code on a PHP file, this work fine. I did also try to call directly the code in my public function and this is all i got is "L'image ne peut être affichée car elle contient des erreurs." mean in english "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

Comment: Comment the Content-Type header (so that your browser will not try to interpret the result as an image), and check again. Also, have you checked already, what the error log has to say?

Comment: My browser need to interpret this as an image to pass it through <img src="CAPTCHA-generate-image.php"> -> CAPTCHA-generate-image.php is the PHP file that generate the session and the image / The public function  CAPTCHA_shortcode_function is here only to display the CAPTCHA on shortcode call. This is only happening in wordpress. Maybe the method that i use is not valid in the wordpress architecture.

Comment: _"My browser need to interpret this as an image"_ - yes, but only once it is working ... Right now, you are trying to find the error - so comment it out, and then check what result the browser actually shows you. If any PHP error messages made their way into the output, then of course the browser will not be able to display this as a valid image. But you won't see any potential error messages contained in it either, as long as you tell the browser it is supposed to interpret this as an image.

Answer (score 1):

We did find a solution :

```
    imagepng($captcha_image,"captcha_image.png");
    $imgData = file_get_contents('captcha_image.png');
    imagedestroy($captcha_image);

    // $imgData = ob_get_clean();

    return $imgData;
```

Then call it in the function like this

```
        ob_start();
        $imgData = $this->CAPTCHA_generate();

        ?>

        <div id="CAPTCHA_box">
            <label for="captcha">Entrez les </label><br>
            <?php echo '<img class="captcha_image" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($imgData).'" />'; ?>
            <i class="fas fa-redo refresh_captcha"></i>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha_challenge" pattern="[A-Z]{6}">
        </div>

        <?php

        $CAPTCHA = ob_get_clean();

        return $CAPTCHA;
```